# How to add eventListener to elemen in webpack modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, addeventlistener

I have javascript application building on modules. I am using webpack. I want to add eventlistener to element. But i can't do it. I receive the error "ReferenceError: x is not defined". Where in my app i should place my eventlistener function. It works if i write function inline, but i don't want to do that.

Here is my app.js file (entry point).

```
import {Main} from "./components/Main";
import './style.css'

export default (function () {
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = Main();
}());
```

Component with element i want to have eventlistener - onclick in  element:

```
import {CompanyContainer} from "./CompanyContainer";

export const UserContainer = user => {
    return (
        `
        <a href="#" onclick="">${user.getFullName()}</a>
        <div class="user-details hide">
            <p>Birthday: ${user.getBirthDay()}</p>
            <p><img src="" width="100px"></p>
            ${CompanyContainer(user.companyId)}
        </div>
        `
        )
};
```

Comment: What is the listener you're trying to add?

Comment: simple click listener

Answer (score 1):

Quick idea:

```js
const e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = yourHTMLCode;
e.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', yourListenerFunction);
```

Edit: I would rewrite your component in this manner:

```
import {CompanyContainer} from "./CompanyContainer";

export const UserContainer = (user, onClick) => {
    const html = `
        <a href="#">${user.getFullName()}</a>
        <div class="user-details hide">
            <p>Birthday: ${user.getBirthDay()}</p>
            <p><img src="" width="100px"></p>
            ${CompanyContainer(user.companyId)}
        </div>
        `;
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = html;
    element.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', onClick);
    return element;
};
```

This way you can pass you listener during container creation.

Comment: i want to add listnener inside this component. Or i can't? There is only one way?

Comment: It's not a good idea to pass plain HTML in the first place. Use that code in a component creation and return HTML element with you code inside of it.

Comment: i wrote code inside app.js file and it works fine. But i will have many listeners and it's not a good idead to place them there.

Comment: I added my idea to the response.

Comment: Listener does not work with this approach

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code and started a fully functional example at github(https://github.com/lalosh/stackoverflow-webpack-event-listener) you can check it yourself.

notice that you didn't even pass an event handler in your code, but assuming you've passed one like

```js
  function onClickHandler(event){...}

  "<a onclick="onClickHandler(event)"> ....
```

the `onClickHandler` won't be called successfully because it's scroped to the file and not to the global object (`window`)

to fix simply attach the event to the global object `window`

```js
  window.onClickHandler = function onClickHandler(event){...}

  "<a onclick="onClickHandler(event)"> ....
```

and note that you can use `addEventListener` (more preferend)instead of directly attaching the event listener from inside `html`, I suggest you check the comparison here
[addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to rewrite my code and made with document.creatreElement instead of innerHTML. And it works. A little bit more lines of code but works and conceptual right.
Thanks for the help.